DSolve gives zero for wave equation with inhomogeneous term involving trigonometric function
Bug introduced after 13.3, persisting through 14.1.
Report to WRI [CASE:5209965]

I encountered difficulties while using DSolve to solve an exercise from the textbook. It is a wave equation with Neumann boundary conditions:
$\begin{cases}u_{t t}-a^2 u_{x x}=A \cos \frac{\pi x}{l} \sin \omega t, & 0<x<l, \quad t>0 \\ u_x(0, t)=0, \quad u_x(l, t)=0 & \\ u(x, 0)=0, \quad u_t(x, 0)=0 & \end{cases}$
The following code only provides the trivial solution when solving this problem:
Clear["Global`*"];

waveEq1 = 
  D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] - a^2 D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == 
   A*Cos[(Pi*x)/l]*Sin[ω*t];

bc1 = {(D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, (D[u[x, t], x] /. x -> l) == 0};
initCond1 = {u[x, 0] == 0, (D[u[x, t], t] /. t -> 0) == 0};

sol1 = DSolve[{waveEq1, initCond1, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, t}]
sol1 = Assuming[a > 0 && t >= 0 && l > 0 && ω > 0 && l > x > 0,
   FullSimplify[sol1]]

Output:
$\left\{\left\{\mathrm{u}[\mathrm{x}, \mathrm{t}] \rightarrow\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0 & \mathrm{~K}[\mathbf{1}] \in \mathbb{Z} \& \& \mathrm{~K}[\mathbf{1}] \geq \mathbf{1} \\ \text { Indeterminate } & \text { True }\end{array}\right\}\right.\right.$
The solution obtained in the textbook using the eigenfunction expansion method is:
$u(x, t)=\frac{A l}{\pi a} \frac{1}{\omega^2-\left(\frac{\pi a}{l}\right)^2}\left[\omega \sin \frac{\pi a t}{l}-\frac{\pi a}{l} \sin \omega t\right] \cos \frac{\pi x}{l}$
However, if the boundary conditions and initial conditions are removed, the general solution of the wave equation can be obtained:
Clear["Global`*"];
waveEq1 = 
  D[u[x, t], {t, 2}] - a^2 D[u[x, t], {x, 2}] == 
   A*Cos[(Pi*x)/l]*Sin[ω*t];
sol1 = DSolve[{waveEq1}, u[x, t], {x, t}]

output:
$\left\{\left\{u[x, t] \rightarrow-\frac{A \operatorname{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi x}{l}-t \omega\right]}{2\left(\frac{a^2 \pi^2}{l^2}-\omega^2\right)}+\frac{A \operatorname{Sin}\left[\frac{\pi x}{l}+t \omega\right]}{2\left(\frac{a^2 \pi^2}{l^2}-\omega^2\right)}+\mathbb{C}_1\left[t+\frac{x}{a}\right]+\mathbb{C}_2\left[t-\frac{x}{a}\right]\right\}\right\}$
I would like to know what went wrong. Why does my code fail to obtain the non-trivial solution given in the textbook?

version 13.3 gives the correct answer:

Obviously a bug, version 12.3 gives the correct answer:

Please report it to WRI. Luckily, this problem is relatively simple to circumvent even in version 14.1, and I have a reasonable guess for what goes wrong in DSolve.
I believe the underlying issue is the same as discussed in the following post:
Usage of Assuming for Integration
This issue is frequently encountered by guys trying to solve PDE exercise related to series expansion. The reason might be that, this type of problem owns a relatively simple solution (the summation no longer shows up in the final result!) so is considered suitable for manual solving. Some examples:
Fourier series solution for Laplace equation in polar coordinates results in Power::infy and Infinity::indet
Error in Fourier Method for PDE
In short, currently Integrate owns the following behavior:
Assuming[{k ∈ PositiveIntegers}, 
 Integrate[Cos[k π x] Cos[π x], {x, 0, 1}]]
(* 0 *)

Please read the linked posts above for more info. In this post I'll focus on circumventing the problem. The idea is simple: let's avoid integration with improper assumption that probably has happened internally. This can be easily achieved by introducing a general inhomogeneous term f[x, t] instead of the specific one:
With[{u = u[x, t]}, eq = D[u, {t, 2}] - a^2 D[u, {x, 2}] == f[x, t];
  ic = {u == 0, D[u, t] == 0} /. t -> 0;
  bc = D[u, x] == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> l}}
  ];

solmid = DSolve[{eq, ic, bc}, u[x, t], {x, t}]


Notice if we introduce K[1] ∈ PositiveIntegers assumption for the marked integration, it'll improperly evaluate to 0:
Assuming[{{K[1]} ∈ PositiveIntegers}, 
 Block[{f = {x, t} |-> A Cos[(π x)/l] Sin[ω t]}, 
  Integrate[(Sqrt[2] Cos[(π x K[1])/l] f[x, K[2]])/Sqrt[l], {x, 0, 
    l}]]]
(* 0 *)

So we substitute f into solmid in the following manner:
sol = Block[{f = {x, t} |-> A Cos[(π x)/l] Sin[ω t]}, 
  solmid // Activate // 
   Simplify[#, {a > 0, l > 0, K[1] ∈ PositiveIntegers}] &]



A way to hack Integrate into giving a piecewise solution that DSolve can handle:
Internal`InheritedBlock[{Integrate},
  Unprotect@Integrate;
  Integrate[f_, {x, 0, l}, 
     opts___] /; ! TrueQ[$in] && ! FreeQ[f, K[1]] := 
   Block[{$in = True},
    Piecewise[{
      {Integrate[f /. K[1] -> 1, {x, 0, l}, opts], K[1] == 1}},
     Integrate[f, {x, 0, l}, opts]]
    ];
  Protect@Integrate;
  
  DSolve[{waveEq1, initCond1, bc1}, u[x, t], {x, t}
   , Assumptions -> 
    a > 0 && t > 0 && l > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && l > x > 0]
  ] // Simplify[#, 
   a > 0 && t > 0 && l > 0 && \[Omega] > 0 && l > x > 0 && 
    K[1] \[Element] PositiveIntegers] &
(*
{{u[x, t] -> (
   A l^2 Cos[(\[Pi] x)/
     l] (-l \[Omega] Sin[(a \[Pi] t)/l] + a \[Pi] Sin[t \[Omega]]))/(
   a^3 \[Pi]^3 - a l^2 \[Pi] \[Omega]^2)}}
*)


Aha, so my guess is indeed right. (+1) of course.

@xzczd Yep. I thought you knew. Actually, I read the question and thought I bet I know what this is. Verified it. Went back to post and realized you had answered already hours before and with the same explanation. So +1 to you. Then an hour or so later, it occurred to me that Piecewise might fix it. Then I thought, it might be a useful strategy to add in special cases that the generic answer of Integrate or Sum misses. Hence I posted it.
